# AnyLogic - Creating new Agent remove _value

Tags: anylogic, agent

I want to create a new Agent out of a database. The agent should have several parameters like material type, length, ect.
My Problem is, that i get a lot of errors, trying to define my agent with java code. I think the problem results out of line 868 and 869 in my main code. AnyLogic has a problem defining the VALUE of an agent trough a code block.
So how can I "delete" or remove the
`Agent _value; _value =` ?

Here's a picture: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDFaX.png)

I have seen a program like mine in the past WITHOUT these two lines. So I know it's possible, but I don't know how. Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not instantiate agents using `MyAgent newAgent = new MyAgent(...)`

Always instantiate agents into (empty) populations using `add_MyAgentPopulation(...)`